# How to save an array of objects into a mongoose db

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to save a leader board made of objects nested in an array. I want to save it in my database, but I have not been able to create the right schema and I don't think I that is the best way to go. 
When I run the code I get the error of:

"LeaderBoardSchema is not a constructor".

What is the appropriate way of creating a schema that I need.

I have tried many variations looking online, but I keep getting the " LeaderBoardSchema is not a constructor".

The examples from other questions on S.O have not been able to help me much.

```js
 
 
 // leaderboard object that i want to save
 leaderBoard = [
        leaderOne=   {
            name: 'Ultimate Beast',
            score: 2
        },
        leaderTwo=  {
            name: 'Masked Titan',
            score: 9
        },
        leaderThree=  {
            name: 'Oranolio',
            score: 7
        },
        leaderFour=  {
            name: 'Popularkiya',
            score:1
        },
        leaderFive=  {
            name: 'Bootecia',
            score: 11
        },
    ];




// Database schema 


const Schema = mongoose.Schema()

const LeaderBoardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   leaderBoard:{
    leaderOne :   {
        name: String,
        score: Number
    },
    leaderTwo :  {
        name: String,
        score: Number
    },
    leaderThree :  {
        name: String,
        score: Number
    },
    leaderFour :  {
        name: String,
        score:Number
    },
    leaderFive :  {
        name: String,
        score: Number
    }
   }
  }, {collection: 'leaderboard-data'});

const PlayerData = mongoose.model('LeaderBoard Data', LeaderBoardSchema);



// My attempt 


const leaderBoardToSave = new LeaderBoardSchema({
        leaderBoard:{
            leaderOne :   {
                name: 'asdf',
                score: 12
            },
            leaderTwo :  {
                name: 'sfgh',
                score: 12
            },
            leaderThree :  {
                name: 'weh',
                score: 12
            },
            leaderFour :  {
                name: 'asdf',
                score:12
            },
            leaderFive :  {
                name: 'asdf',
                score: 12
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your `leaderBoard` field is an object. To model an array of objects do the following with your schema:

```
const LeaderBoardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   leaderBoard: [
    {
        name: String,
        score: Number
    }
   ]
  }, {collection: 'leaderboard-data'});
```

as for the issue with the schema constructor. You're creating the mongoose model as follows `const PlayerData = mongoose.model('LeaderBoard Data', LeaderBoardSchema);`. But then you do `new LeaderBoardSchema({...})`. You need to use the mongoose model `PlayerData` instead. so to create a new leaderboard:

```
const leaderBoardToSave = new PlayerData({
        leaderBoard: [
           {
              name: 'asdf',
              score: 12
           },
           {
              name: 'gds',
              score: 12
           },
           {
              name: 'adad',
              score: 12
           },
       ]
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. Got it to work!